# Object-oriented design in Desktop-like web app

Tags: javascript, python, oop

I am working toward a small webapp that I would like to have a desktop-like feel to it.  The application will use python on the backend and I will be using hand-coded javascript (on top of jquery, etc.) on the web side.  I have a few objects that I would like to pass back-and-forth between the two and wondered about how folks approach the issue.  As an example, I have a "filter" that I will be treating as an object:

```
filter: { 
   name:'genericGeneFilter', 
   type:'geneFilter',
   symbol:'ExampleSymbol',
   includeExclude:'include'}
```

How do folks do the following:

1. Define the classes in *one* place (so that server-side and client-side both get the definition)
2. Define the user interaction (form fields, appearance, etc.) conveniently
3. Pass data to/from server/client.  Use serialized forms, json, gets/posts, or html?
4. Keep client and server in sync with regard to "objects" being passed back-and-forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you can take a look at [backbonejs](http://backbonejs.org/)

> Backbone.js gives structure to web applications by providing models with key-value binding and custom events, collections with a rich API of enumerable functions, views with declarative event handling, and connects it all to your existing API over a RESTful JSON interface.

There is another js library called [emberjs](http://emberjs.com/) that seems to do much more than backbonejs.:

> Ember.js (formerly SproutCore 2.0) is a JavaScript framework that does all of the heavy lifting that you'd normally have to do by hand. There are tasks that are common to every web app; Ember.js does those things for you, so you can focus on building killer features and UI. These are the three features that make Ember.js a joy to use: (1) Bindings, (2) Computed properties and (3) Auto-updating templates.

Read more on their [github repo](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js)

Comment: Based on your answer and that of js1568, I found this little post:  http://codebrief.com/2012/01/the-top-10-javascript-mvc-frameworks-reviewed/

Comment: I added that library to my answer just for reference. thanx for mentioning it.

Comment: I'm going to play with emberjs for now, yes.  It looks like it will do far more than what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/). It is a good framework for this kind of web development and includes a view model for user interaction with dynamic binding, sending/receiving of data to server, and automatic data model syncing.

Answer (score 1):

1. Using nodejs on your server is the only way I know of where both server and client could read a single js file. The folks developing the Cordova js library for mobile app UI interaction have been working around the syntax pattern of require js to make their files readable by both client (browser) and server (node js). My app doesn't use any variety of this architecture so I can't speak to it fully, but I'll be perusing this possibility for my next coding upgrade.
2. I'm not sure what you mean by define user interaction. For event listeners, trial and error ( & stackoverflow) has taught me to use object.addEventListener() for cross browser and cross device compatibility. For remote calls to the server I like to create a helper method that proxies all the calls for me. I find this to be the easiest way to process all the success and error messages returned by my server.
3. If you have control of your end user (such as an intranet) and you can reasonably assume everybody is using a modern browser, the XMLHttpRequest() will do the job nicely. If you don't have that kind of control, and need to support older versions of IE, I'd suggest using a library such as jQuery ($.ajax()). All that is assuming you want to use the AJAX design pattern. Websockets are all the new rage and offer better response time when making a call to the server. Websockets are complex to set up and work on a completely different model. With AJAX, you make a call to the server and in turn get a response. With websockets, you "subscribe to a channel" and messages are sent and received independently. That means client A can send some info to the server and then the server can send that same data to client B without client B asking first. I know there are some libraries out there you could use for python that i ran across during my own research several months back.  When using AJAX I prefer to POST data when I have control of the server to make it slightly less easier to see the data for unskilled hackers. To package my data, I like to use native js Dom methods to build JSON objects because I'm OCD about validating form data before sending it. And, then I use JSON.stringify() to make my data ready for sending.
4. Don't fully understand the question. What is the scope of your object on the server? Application level, client level, user level?  That could be handled many different ways depending on the application needs. if you are using websockets as your communication technique, your server can send updates automatically without first requesting from the browser. If using AJAX you client will have to ask for updates or use a technique such as long-polling to simulate websocket like communication.